# tvNext.setOnClickListener giving ERROR

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

```
ERROR LINE:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
    method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
    on a null object reference
```

.JAVA FILE

```
    package co.hangyr.Hangyr.Activity.Camera;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import butterknife.ButterKnife;
    import butterknife.InjectView;
    import co.hangyr.Hangyr.Activity.Home.ActivityHome;
    import co.hangyr.Hangyr.Activity.Others.Footer;
    import co.hangyr.Hangyr.R;

    public class ActivityCamera extends Footer implements View.OnClickListener {
        static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;

        ImageView imageView;
       /* static final int SECOND_PIC = 2;
        static final int THIRD_PIC = 3;
        static final int FORTH_PIC = 4;
        static final int FIFTH_PIC = 5;
    */

        @InjectView(R.id.ivFirstPic)
        ImageView firstPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.ivCapture)
        ImageView ivCapture;
        @InjectView(R.id.ivFlipCamera)
        ImageView flipCamera;
        @InjectView(R.id.ivFlash)
        ImageView flash;
        @InjectView(R.id.tvUploadFromGallery)
        TextView tvUploadFromGallery;
        @InjectView(R.id.ivSecondPic)
        ImageView secondPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.ivThirdPic)
        ImageView thirdPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.ivForthPic)
        ImageView forthPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.ivFifthPic)
        ImageView fifthPic;

        @InjectView(R.id.ivJustClicked)
        FrameLayout justClicked;
        // @InjectView(R.id.tvNextEditPic)
        TextView tvNext;

        @InjectView(R.id.bDeleteFirstPic)
        Button deleteFirstPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.bDeleteSecondPic)
        Button deleteSecondPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.bDeleteThirdPic)
        Button deleteThirdPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.bDeleteForthPic)
        Button deleteForthPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.bDeleteFifthPic)
        Button deleteFifthPic;
        @InjectView(R.id.tvCancel)
        TextView tvCancel;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.camera);
            ButterKnife.inject(this);
            tvNext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNextEditPic);
            tvNext.setOnClickListener(this);
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            justClicked.addView(mCameraPreview);

            ivCapture.setOnClickListener(this);
            tvUploadFromGallery.setOnClickListener(this);

            firstPic.setOnClickListener(this);
            deleteFirstPic.setOnClickListener(this);
            deleteSecondPic.setOnClickListener(this);
            deleteThirdPic.setOnClickListener(this);
            deleteForthPic.setOnClickListener(this);
            deleteFifthPic.setOnClickListener(this);

            tvCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        private Camera getCameraInstance() {
            Camera camera = null;
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                flipCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                flash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // cannot get camera or does not exist
            }
            return camera;
        }

        Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
                if (pictureFile == null) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

                    firstPic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "MyCameraApp");

            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            // Create a media file name
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                    .format(new Date());
            File mediaFile;
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

            return mediaFile;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.ivCapture:
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    break;

                case R.id.ivFirstPic:
                    mCameraPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mCameraPreview);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                    deleteFirstPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;

                case R.id.tvCancel:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityHome.class));
                    break;

                case R.id.tvNextEditPic:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadPic.class));
                    break;

                case R.id.bDeleteFirstPic:
                    firstPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_item_cam);
                    deleteFirstPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;

                case R.id.bDeleteSecondPic:
                    secondPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_item_cam);
                    deleteSecondPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;

                case R.id.bDeleteThirdPic:
                    thirdPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_item_cam);
                    deleteThirdPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;

                case R.id.bDeleteForthPic:
                    forthPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_item_cam);
                    deleteForthPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;

                case R.id.bDeleteFifthPic:
                    fifthPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_item_cam);
                    deleteFifthPic.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                firstPic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            }
        }
    }
```

.XML FILE

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/backgroundApp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llNameBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/cancelS"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNextEditPic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/nextS"
                android:textColor="#fd676a"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="375dp">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ivJustClicked"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivFlipCamera"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                            android:padding="8dp"

                            android:src="@drawable/flip_camera" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivFlash"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/flash_icon" />
                    </FrameLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvUploadFromGallery"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:padding="18dp"
                        android:text="@string/galleryS"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCapture"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/capture" />

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/camera_pic_added"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think the issue is not on textview Its written Imageview.setOnclicklistener.
Please comment the onclick listener for imageview and try again once more

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Bind`instead of `@InjectView`

@InjectView was replaced June 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to initialize this variable `ivFirstPic`:

```
ivFirstPic.setOnClickListener(this);
```